# prepend a header to .csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, finance, google-finance

my current code able to fetch historical data from Google finance but missing the first row to label each column.
I want the output as below

> Stock,Date,Time,Open, High,Low,Close,Volume 
>   CCK,2015-12-30,00:00:00,1.05,1.05,0.99,1.00,157800
>   CCK,2015-12-31,00:00:00,0.98,1.03,0.98,1.02,55300

```
 stocklist=['CCK','MSFT','AA','AAPL']
        stocklen=len(stocklist)

for x in range(1,stocklen,1):
    q = GoogleQuote(stocklist[x],'2015-12-21')
    header = ['Stock','Date','Time','Open','High','Low','Close']
    print header                                             
    print q                                                   
    q.write_csv(stocklist[x]+".csv")
    with open(stocklist[x]+".csv",'a') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(['Stock','Date','Time','Open','High','Low','Close'])
```

However, the output is at the last row as such

> CCK,2015-12-30,00:00:00,1.05,1.05,0.99,1.00,157800
>   CCK,2015-12-31,00:00:00,0.98,1.03,0.98,1.02,55300
>   Stock,Date,Time,Open, High,Low,Close,Volume

Comment: You are appending so it makes sense it is at the end, if you want to prepend you will have to overwrite the file storing all the content and prepending or writing to a tempfile

Comment: i need to do the data analysis with the label in first row. Since I have many .csv files, how to add the label in first row?

Comment: @bkcollection Padraic probably wants to say, that since you are appendig to a file (you open it with `a`), but want to place headers at the top, you may want to use temporary file to dump appendings. But if you need just write to csv file, you can do this: with open(stocklist[x]+".csv",'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
    w.writerow(...)

Comment: @bkcollection, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888222/adding-a-new-column-on-csv-with-python/31888320#31888320,  after   `wr = csv.writer(...` you would write the header then do whatever you want with the rest of teh data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does `GoogleQuote` come from? Is it from [quotes.py](https://github.com/daodao10/koding/blob/master/chart/quotes.py) ???

If so then your code will already produce CSV files with the header line, the only difference being that the first column is labelled `Symbol` rather than `Stock`. If you object to that label you can change it like this:

```
import csv
import datetime
from itertools import repeat

header = ['Stock', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
stocklist=['CCK','MSFT','AA','AAPL']
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 21)
#end = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31)
for stock in stocklist:
    q = GoogleQuote(stock, start.strftime('%F'))
    data = zip(repeat(q.symbol), q.date, q.time, q.open_, q.high, q.low, q.close, q.volume)
    with open('{}.csv'.format(stock), 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(header)
        w.writerows(data)
```

---

You could use `pandas`:

```
import datetime
import pandas.io.data as web

stocklist=['CCK','MSFT','AA','AAPL']
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 21)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31)
for stock in stocklist:
    data = web.DataReader(stock, 'google', start, end)
    data.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(stock))
```

This will create separate CSV files for each stock for the range of dates inclusive, with header line:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
```

The differences in output between `pandas` and your code is:

- Stock not present as first column in CSV. Since each file is named
  according to the stock it is not required in the file itself.
- Time column not present. Quotes are for a date so the time may not be relevant.

If you really must have stock and time columns these can be added to the data frame.

```
for stock in stocklist:
    data = web.DataReader(stock, 'google', start, end)
    data.insert(0, 'Time', [ts.time() for ts in data.index])
    data.reset_index(inplace=True)    # make Date a proper column
    data.insert(0, 'Stock', stock)
    data.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(stock), index=False)
```

Note that the date column is a timestamp, so adding the time column may not be necessary. Instead you could omit addition of the Time column and format the date with:

```
    data.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(stock), index=False, date_format='%F %T')
```

Comment: I wish I can use pandas. I need to download some stocks from foreign stocks exchange and pandas only support US stocks.

Comment: I think that you can access foreign stocks by prefixing the stock code with an exchange code, e.g. LON:BARC pulls quotes for Barclays bank from the LSE.

Comment: @bkcollection: updated answer to use `GoogleQuote` class... I think.

Comment: @mhwake, it works!!Change q = GoogleQuote(stock,start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) working perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @bkcollection: good. You might want to upvote and accept the answer then ;)